# Failure : Build failed with an exception

Tags: build

Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Task 'stacktrace' not found in root project 'GatePass14mar17'.
- Try:
  Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

I am getting this error while running the application

Comment: // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: This is my gradle file :-

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.copia21.gatepass14mar17"minSdkVersion 19targetSdkVersion 24
versionCode 1versionName "1.0" }buildTypes { release { minifyEnabledfalseproguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguardrules.pro' } }}dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'}

Comment: I had deleted .gradel file, cleaned and re- build the project yet nothing happend.